# Command to see how large a MapR-DB Table is?

Tags: hbase, mapr

Is there a command to see how big a MapR-DB table is?

I tried du -sh on the POSIX client but all of my tables are the same size, so I assume this is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you experimented, using the file system does not help that much. Also when you are using a MapR DB Table you cannot use the `hbase shell status` command.

The solution is to use the `maprcli table info` command, something like:

`maprcli table info -path  '/apps/table01' -json`

This will give you many information about the table.

I invite you to look at the documentation:

- [MapR 5.0 Documentation](http://doc.mapr.com/display/MapR/table+info)
- [MapR 5.1 Documentation](http://maprdocs.mapr.com/51/index.html#ReferenceGuide/table-info_28217868.html)